# Method Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile::validate does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-package

Hello All I am trying to get validate file in laravel with custom package but i give the error of the

> "Method Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile::validate does not exist."

so please know what is a problem.
MyController code:

```
$files=$request->file('image');
if($files){ 
    $oGreetr = new Greetr();
    return $oGreetr->file_size($files);
}
```

Package Code:

```
public function file_size($file){
    //return $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    
    return $file->validate([
        'image' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
    ]);
}
```

Please help me to solve these error..

Comment: `$this->validate()` valid

Answer (score 0):

I think issue is passing wrong param  to package method. `$request->file` doesn't have validate method. So you have to do pass `$request` to package method

```
$files=$request->file('image');
if($files){ 
    $oGreetr = new Greetr();
    return $oGreetr->file_size($request);
}
```

and in package

```
public function file_size($request){
   
    
    return $request->validate([
        'image' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As $file variable does not have a validate function. You can you the following method to validate the custom variable. Also, use the Validator facade.

```
public function file_size($request){
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'image' => 'required',
    ]);
    return $validator;
  }
```